# No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000 error

Tags: android

I have created a fragment where user can edit their information but whenever i run the application in android studio, it always gives me this error:No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000. I cannot open up this web page from my navigation drawer also.

```
package com.example.redir.wealthtrack;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.redir.wealthtrack.db.InfoDataSource;
import com.example.redir.wealthtrack.db.LimitDataSource;
import com.example.redir.wealthtrack.model.Info;
import com.example.redir.wealthtrack.model.Limit;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class infoFragment extends Fragment {

    public InfoDataSource infoDataSource;
    String textInEditText;
    String textInEditText2;
    String textInEditText3;


    public infoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("User Target");


        infoDataSource = new InfoDataSource(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        infoDataSource.open();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_userinfo, container, false);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        final EditText editText2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText editText3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText.setText(infoDataSource.getFirst().getName());
        editText2.setText((int) infoDataSource.getFirst().getIncome());
        editText3.setText((int) infoDataSource.getFirst().getGoal());

        Button AddButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                a_builder.setMessage("Confirm?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Info newInfo = new Info ();
                                newInfo.setName(editText.getText().toString());
                                newInfo.setIncome(Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString()));
                                newInfo.setGoal(Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString()));
                                createInfo(newInfo);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                alert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#08ae9e'>Confirmation</font>"));
                alert.show();
            }
        });

        Button EditButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.EditButton);
        EditButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder a_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                a_builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to edit?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Info newInfo = new Info();
                                newInfo.setId(1);
                                newInfo.setName(editText.getText().toString());
                                newInfo.setIncome(Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString()));
                                newInfo.setGoal(Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString()));
                                updateInfo(newInfo);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = a_builder.create();
                alert.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#08ae9e'>Confirmation</font>"));
                alert.show();

            }
        });

        textInEditText = editText.getText().toString();
        textInEditText2 = editText2.getText().toString();
        textInEditText3 = editText3.getText().toString();
        if(textInEditText.matches("")){
            EditButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if(!textInEditText.matches("")){
            AddButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if(textInEditText2.matches("")){
            EditButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if(!textInEditText2.matches("")){
            AddButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if(textInEditText3.matches("")){
            EditButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else if(!textInEditText3.matches("")){
            AddButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return view;

    }

    public static void showToast(Context context, String text) {
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void createInfo (Info info) {
        infoDataSource.createInfo(info);
        showToast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Target added");
    }

    private void updateInfo (Info info) {
        infoDataSource.updateInfo(info);
        showToast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Target updated");
    }



THE DATA


package com.example.redir.wealthtrack.db;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.redir.wealthtrack.model.Info;
import com.example.redir.wealthtrack.model.Limit;

import java.net.URI;


/**
 * Created by redir on 24/2/2016.
 */
public class InfoDataSource {
    public static final String LOGTAG="WEALTHTRACK";

    SQLiteOpenHelper dbhelper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    //Create some Static Variable for the Column Names
    private static final String[] allColumns = {
            WealthDBOpenHelper.INFO_ID,
            WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
            WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_INCOME,
            WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_GOAL
    };

    public InfoDataSource(Context context) {
        dbhelper = new WealthDBOpenHelper(context);
    }

    //open the DB to edit
    public void open() {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database opened");
        database = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    //Closing the DB
    public void close() {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Database closed");
        dbhelper.close();
    }

    public Info createInfo (Info info) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME, info.getName());
        values.put(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_INCOME, info.getIncome());
        values.put(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_GOAL, info.getGoal());
        long insertid = database.insert(WealthDBOpenHelper.TABLE_INFO, null, values);
        info.setId(insertid);
        return info;
    }
    public boolean updateInfo (Info info) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME, info.getName());
        values.put(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_INCOME, info.getIncome());
        values.put(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_GOAL, info.getGoal());
        String where = WealthDBOpenHelper.INFO_ID + "=" + info.getId();
        int result = database.update(WealthDBOpenHelper.TABLE_INFO, values, where, null);
        return (result ==1);
    }


    public Info getFirst() {
        Info info = new Info();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(WealthDBOpenHelper.TABLE_INFO, allColumns,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            info.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(WealthDBOpenHelper.INFO_ID)));
            info.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_NAME)));
            info.setIncome(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_INCOME))));
            info.setGoal(Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WealthDBOpenHelper.COLUMN_GOAL))));
        }
        return info;
    }

}


THE LAYOUT

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".infoFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textcolor"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:background="#08ae9e"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:hint="Monthly income"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textcolor"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:background="#08ae9e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:hint="Saving goal"
        android:textColorHint="@color/textcolor"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:background="#08ae9e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/AddButton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#08ae9e"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Edit"
        android:id="@+id/EditButton"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#08ae9e"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/AddButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/AddButton"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/AddButton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Geralt_Encore is correct. You should use :

```
editText2.setText(String.valueOf(infoDataSource.getFirst().getIncome()));
editText3.setText(String.valueOf(infoDataSource.getFirst().getGoal()));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
        editText2.setText((int) infoDataSource.getFirst().getIncome());
        editText3.setText((int) infoDataSource.getFirst().getGoal());
```

You are accidently using overloaded version of `setText(int resId)` instead of `setText(String text)` and it can't find string resource with identifier 0 in that case.